# PM2 Won't Start Inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, pm2

Trying to get a node app running and reloading from a volume inside docker, using docker-compose.

**The goal is to have the app running inside the container, without losing the ability to edit/reload the code outside the container.**

I've been through [PM2's docker integration advice](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/) and using `keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine:latest` as a base image.

The `docker-compose.yml` file defines a simple web service.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "${HOST_PORT}:${APP_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Which uses a fairly simple Dockerfile.

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine:latest
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Which calls `npm start`:

```
{
  "start": "pm2-docker process.yml --watch"
}
```

Which refers to `process.yml`:

```
apps:
  - script: './index.js'
    name: 'server'
```

Running `npm start` locally works fine—PM2 gets the node process running and watching for changes to the code.

However, as soon as I try and run it inside a container instead, I get the following error on startup:

```
Attaching to app_web_1
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
web_1  | [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
web_1  |
web_1  |   error: missing required argument `file|json|stdin|app_name|pm_id'
web_1  |
app_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Can't find any good examples for a hello world with the pm2-docker binary, and I've got no idea why `pm2-docker` would refuse to work, especially as it's running above the official `pm2-docker-alpine` image.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://francolaiuppa.com/2015/11/14/dockerfile-for-nodejs-development-with-nodemon-and-forever/) could help you.

Comment: @Sryther Thanks, but this problem is specific to PM2. I can get Nodemon running & reloading inside docker, but that's only really good for development.

Comment: Can you try to use in your Dockerfile `CMD ["pm2-docker", "process.yml", "--watch"]` and change in the `process.yml` the value of `script` to `'index.js'` instead of `'./index.js'` ? Just to test

Comment: @Sryther Already tried both, same results.

Answer (score 1):

To activate the --watch option, instead of passing the --watch option to pm2-docker, just set the watch option to true in the yml configuration file:

```
apps:
  - script: './index.js'
    name: 'server'
    watch : true
```

Comment: Thanks @Unitech! Since asking, switched over to using `pm2-dev` when I'm developing. When developing inside the container would you suggest using `pm2-docker` with `watch: true` instead?

Comment: Yes exactly, while developing use pm2-dev (watch enabled by default) and when you are ready to ship the container use pm2-docker